# How to prevent resizing a Chrome Packaged App?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I've just jumped into developing apps for chrome, and just started with the "Hello World" example. My first thing I wanted to change is to prevent resizing of the window, I've searched and got nothing... :(

So, is this even possible right now?

*Also, reading the documentation it says 'panel' is non-resizable,but at least in windows it is...*

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use the resizable flag.

```
chrome.app.window.create("YourPage.html", {
    "bounds": {
        "width": 320,
        "height": 240,
    },
    "resizable": false,
});
```

Comment: Can you tell the window to open fullscreen?

Comment: @Greg, what about preventing it from scaling only up or only down? Let's say I would't like a user to scale a window below 300x300?

Answer (score 3):

Specify min and max width and height when creating a window to constrain it. You can set min and max to the same value to make the window non-resizable.

E.g., here is a modified main.js from the [Hello World](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/tree/master/hello-world) sample:

```
chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(function() {
  chrome.app.window.create('index.html',
    {minWidth: 500, minHeight: 309,
     maxWidth: 500, maxHeight: 309});
});
```

For more details, see the [app window api](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/app.window.html).

Comment: This is now deprecated. Use `resizable: false`.